# Getting totals by year

Tags: r

I have the following DF.

```
Fund   Name   Assets_Jan2000 Asset_Feb2000 Asets_Mar2000
 x      Y          20234        654654         13154
 A      T          45646        46546544       
 K      L          464654                      464
```

There are many more columns - All the way through to Dec2017.

I would like to get the totals each month (e.g. Jan 2000) as well as each year (e.g. 2000, 2001 etc).

I tried the following

```
total <- colSums(assets[, c(3:365)], na.rm = TRUE)
total1 <- as.data.frame(total).
```

This gives me the totals by month. I'm not sure how to get to the totals by year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get totals by year one way would be to split the data by column name, extract the year and take `sum` of all the values. In base R, we can use `split.default` with `sapply`

```
df1 <- df[,c(3:365)]
sapply(split.default(df1, sub(".*?(\\d+$)", "\\1", names(df1))), function(x) 
       sum(unlist(x), na.rm = TRUE))
```

Or using a bit of reshaping with `dplyr` we can do

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  tidyr::gather(key, value, -Fund, -Name) %>%
  mutate(Year = sub(".*?(\\d+$)", "\\1", key)) %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(value, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can do this in `tidyverse` with

```
library(tidyverse)
gather(df1, Year, Val, matches("^As+et"), na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
   group_by(Year = readr::parse_number(Year)) %>%
   summarise(Val = sum(Val))
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
aggregate(values ~ cbind(Year = sub("\\D+", "", ind)), 
             stack(df1[-(1:2)]), FUN = sum, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Or using `aggregate` with the results of `colSums` from the OP's post

```
aggregate(values ~ cbind(Year = sub("\\D+", "", ind)), 
       stack(colSums(df1[-(1:2)], na.rm = TRUE)), FUN = sum)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(und = c("x", "A", "K"), Name = c("Y", "T", "L"
), Assets_Jan2000 = c(20234L, 45646L, 464654L), Asset_Feb2000 = c(654654L, 
46546544L, NA), Asets_Mar2000 = c(13154L, NA, 464L)),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```